# Versioning Architecture in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, version, versioning

I have been trying to look into the versioning architecture for Microsoft Sharepoint. Does anyone know about the same?

Answer (score 0):

The major versions of SharePoint are: SharePoint 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, and SharePoint Online.

For detailed information, refer to following article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint#Versions